# How to hidden Querystring in nodejs + ajax

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, express

I'm wan't to make a basic login form.
I'm using method Post in ajax fucntion, but querystring still show in here...

What can't I do (☝◞‸◟)☞
Thank for any help!

[[image: here is login form][1]]

[image: but querystring still unhidden]

[image: my ajax code]

Comment: Accept an ``event`` parameter in ``Login`` function and call ``event.preventDefault()``. That will fix your issue. ``Login = (event) => {  event.preventDefault(); ... }``

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what is happening is when you click on submit button your original form is also submitting directly to the **backend**, your form should be submit from **Ajax** call. So, what you can do just add following line in the starting of your **Login** function:

```
Login = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
    /*.. your remaining code*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm put the button submit out of the form tag and it works for me.